# Bitnami stacks compatible with Ubuntu 11?

Tags: ubuntu, compatibility, ubuntu-11.04, stack

Has anyone successfully installed Bitnami [native stacks](http://bitnami.org/stacks) on Ubuntu 11?

After changing the bin file's permissions to allow it to be executable, I get the following error in the Terminal:

`bitnami-dokuwiki-2011-05-25a-0-linux-x64-installer.bin: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string` for the Docuwiki stack, and

`bitnami-lampstack-3.0.6-0-linux-x64-installer.bin: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string` for the LAMP stack.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running these installers in an Ubuntu 64 bits system? Could you post the result of "uname -a" command? BitNami has just released new 64 bit versions, could you check the new installer versions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about him, but my `uname -a` gives the following:

```
2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon April 03:31:50 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/LINUX
```

My installation is on an older machine, with classic set (no effects) to get around the fact that it can't use the Unity interface without making the menus impossible to read.

When I try to install the bitnami stack, using the windowed version to set the bits for executable, it fails to find an executable file. Trying again using chmod 744 variation an the command line however seems to work.